# PHP - How to get around a variable having 2 values?

Tags: php, variables

I'm a novice with PHP and would appreciate being steered in the right direction.

I need to be able to have both:

```
if ( !empty($state['books']) ) {
      $state_books = $state['books'];
                        }
```

and

```
if ( !empty($state['books']) ) {
      $state_books = $state['dehd_books'];
                        }
```

Obviously, only the second one is functioning when I have both as I am overwriting the value of the variable $state_books, but I would like to be able to display both results. How do I accomplish this? I know the variable $state_books cannot have two different values. Is it as simple as trying to create an addition variable?

Sorry if this is an XY problem, thanks for your consideration.

Comment: *"Sorry if this is an XY problem"* - This is exactly an XY problem.  Why do you think you need a variable to have two values simultaneously?  When you print the variable, which value would you expect to see and why?  Are you instead looking to create an object with multiple properties?  Or use two variables?  The solution you propose is wrong, but what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What data type will `$state_books` be? a string? an array? Something else?

Comment: I would imagine I should be looking to create an object with multiple properties. I would like the end result to be that the function inside of which this variable is contained prints both $state['books'] as well as $state['dehd_books']. Does that clarify?

Comment: Assuming `$state[ "books" ]` and `$state[ "dehd_books" ]` are both strings, why not just echo both...?

Comment: @CDesign: It sounds like `$state` is already the object you want, no?  I guess if it's scope is limited and you want to transfer values from it to another object in a different scope, or some custom data structure to return, then you should read up on classes and objects in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php  Basically you can create a class which defines your data structure and logical operations, then create an instance of that class and set its properties to the values you want.  That entire class instance is stored in a variable, can be returned from a function, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function could simply return the `$state` array:

```php
function getBooks() {

    /* your other code */

    return $state;

}
```

Assuming that `$state[ "books" ]` is an array, you could then show any individual list item like so - this is assuming you know the index of the item you'd like to display:

```php
<?php $state = getBooks(); ?>

<p><?php echo $state[ "books" ][ 0 ]; ?></p>
```

If you'd like to show all variables inside `$state[ "books" ]`, you can iterate over the array using either a `foreach` or `for` loop - foreach:

```php
foreach ( $state[ "books" ] as $book ) {

    echo $book . "<br>";

}
```

For:

```php
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $state[ "books" ); $i++ ) {

    echo $state[ "books" ][ i ];

}
```